# Is data loss possible when connection is closed

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection

I have large amount of list-structured data which are streaming to handler. Handler is a class which builds `INSERT` or `UPDATE` prepared statement and executes it. All prepared statements are executed in one connection and transaction for now. So, imagine  the situation that connection will be unexpectedly closed from database server, which will obviously lead application to crash. How can i reconnect to database without data loss? Am i right that if i just call `DriverManager.getConnection`, i'll lose all data from previous connection?

Data is a large (1-2 GB) XML containing list of unordered entries and should be uploaded to database with one transaction only, no intermediate transactions.

I use postgres database and jdk7.

Comment: Sounds like database code optimization here: 2 suggestions: 1) Use a pooled `DataSource` to obtain your JDBC connection, and 2) do batch insert/update of your statements instead of doing it individually, one by one.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi "do batch insert/update of your statements" i suppose it'll increase memory usage extremely, as you keep millions of `String` objects in memory.

Comment: one would surely break it up into chunks and batch insert/update those chunks surely. I presume that would be clear to anyone.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi i cant see how it'll save data from loss in case of closed connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, imagine the situation that connection will be unexpectedly closed from database server, which will obviously lead application to crash.

Yep.

> How can i reconnect to database without data loss?

You don't throw away the data on the application side until it's confirmed committed by the database. This might require making sure clients can be asked to send the data again, making the client in turn waiting before you confirm success, writing tempfiles, or whatever.

> Am i right that if i just call DriverManager.getConnection, i'll lose all data from previous connection?

Yes. When the connection is closed the transaction is rolled back.

> Data is a large (1-2 GB) XML containing list of unordered entries and should be uploaded to database with one transaction only, no intermediate transactions.

Then you'd better not crash. Really, I think it's as simple as that. You could proxy the connection via something else that let you recover the connection after the app crashes and restarts, but then it wouldn't know exactly how much of the file it'd already sent to the server. So it'd be unable to continue safely.

Really, you need to either be able to do this in smaller chunks or just accept that if you crash you've got to start again from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll think about another way of uploading data.